# where does the code go when extending the wordpress rest api?

Tags: php, wordpress, rest

I'm helping a friend with his wordpress installation and would like to add some additional fields to the existing REST response for posts.

I've read tyhe documentation at https://developer.wordpress.org/rest-api/extending-the-rest-api/modifying-responses/

The examples show php code that calls functions like register_rest_field which I kinda get but what isbn't clear is where I place that code and how it is executed.

Answer (score 0):

You need to paste that function in your theme's `function.php` file. Function.php file will be in a root in your theme folder.

When you add the script for example,

```
<?php
add_action( 'rest_api_init', function () {
    register_rest_field( 'comment', 'karma', array(
        'get_callback' => function( $comment_arr ) {
            $comment_obj = get_comment( $comment_arr['id'] );
            return (int) $comment_obj->comment_karma;
        },
        'update_callback' => function( $karma, $comment_obj ) {
            $ret = wp_update_comment( array(
                'comment_ID'    => $comment_obj->comment_ID,
                'comment_karma' => $karma
            ) );
            if ( false === $ret ) {
                return new WP_Error(
                  'rest_comment_karma_failed',
                  __( 'Failed to update comment karma.' ),
                  array( 'status' => 500 )
                );
            }
            return true;
        },
        'schema' => array(
            'description' => __( 'Comment karma.' ),
            'type'        => 'integer'
        ),
    ) );
} );
```

It bind the function with `rest_api_init` action. This action will be called before the rest api initialize and your function will be executed first. Doing this you can add additional fields to the same. Hope its clear now.